# Dependent destroy going out of scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ok, so I have 2 models with a `has_many :through` relationship:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :services, :through :servers_services, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :servers_services, :dependent => :destroy

  def destroy!
    options = {:name => self.name, :services => self.services.map { |s| s.attributes }}
    Resque.enqueue(Cluster::DestroyServer, options)
    self.destroy 
  end
end
```

and

```
class Service
  has_many :servers, :through => :servers_services
  has_many :servers_services
end
```

These are connected through:

```
class ServersService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :service
end
```

The `destroy!` method in the Server model previously worked, but now doesn't do what it should.  It should find all `Services` associated with the `Server`, trigger the `Resque` task (which works) and then destroy the `Server` and its associated `Services`.

What is happening however, is that it is destroy ALL `ServerServices` (literally the whole table), not just the ones associated with the `Server` object, which breaks all of the associations.  Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by a broken `postgresql` sequence on the ID column on the servers_services table.  Fixed the sequence so that there is a valid primary key and everything works as expected again.